# Trying to plot power ranking data over time in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a graph of power rankings over time that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8I9K.png)

My data currently looks like this:

**Rank   Week 1 Week 2 Week 3 Week 4** etc.

1      Team 2 Team 2 Team 5 Team 8

2      Team 5 Team 8 Team 8 Team 5

3      Team 6 Team 5 Team 1 Team 4

etc.

What's the best way to transform this data so I can actually make a graph with multiple lines? I feel like it can be done with ggplot but I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to transform your data from a wide format to a long format. You can do this using `gather()` from the `tidyr` package (or `pivot_longer()` for versions>=1.0.0).

Here's an example:

```
library(ggplots)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat <- data.frame(rank = c(1,2,3,4),
                  week1 = c("robins", "sparrows", "pidgeons", "parrots"),
                  week2 = c("robins", "parrots", "sparrows", "pidgeons"),
                  week3 = c("parrots", "robins", "sparrows", "pidgeons"),
                  week4 = c("robins", "sparrows", "parrots", "pidgeons"))

# I don't need this renaming step, but it might help you with your data
names(dat) <- c("rank", paste0("week",1:(ncol(dat)-1) ))

long.dat <- dat %>%
  gather(key="week", value = "team", -rank) %>%
  mutate(week=as.numeric(str_extract(week, "[0-9]+")))

ggplot(data = long.dat, aes(x = week, y = rank, color = team)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

With the output:
[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much man! This worked for me. Really appreciate the renaming step too.

Comment: Happy to help out! If anything is unclear, feel free to ask and I can clarify/explain